# Add google map in html using canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas, drawing

I have a simple drawing canvas that can allow a user to draw, edit, clear and save that drawing. whenever user refreshes his page that saved drawing will appear on the screen until and unless user deletes that image I have this code which is perfectly fine.

```js
var canvas, ctx,
    brush = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        color: '#000000',
        size: 10,
        down: false,
    },
    strokes = [],
    currentStroke = null;

function redraw () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    for (var i = 0; i < strokes.length; i++) {
        var s =strokes[i];
        ctx.strokeStyle = s.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = s.size;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(s.points[0].x, s.points[0].y);
        for (var j = 0; j < s.points.length; j++){
            var p = s.points[j];
            ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}
function init () {
    canvas = $('#draw');
    canvas.attr({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
    });
    ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');


    function mouseEvent (e){
                brush.x = e.pageX;
        brush.y = e.pageY;

        currentStroke.points.push({
            x: brush.x,
            y: brush.y,

        });



        redraw();
    }
    canvas.mousedown(function (e){
        brush.down = true;

        currentStroke = {
            color: brush.color,
            size: brush.size,
            points: [],
        };
        strokes.push(currentStroke);

        mouseEvent(e);
    }) .mouseup(function (e) {
        brush.down = false;

        mouseEvent(e);

        currentStroke = null;
    }) .mousemove(function (e) {
        if (brush.down)
            mouseEvent(e);
    });

    // check if localstorage has an array of strokes saved 
    if(localStorage.getItem('canvas_strokes')) { 
       strokes =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('canvas_strokes'));
      redraw();
    }

  $('#save-to-local-storage').click(function () {
     localStorage.setItem('canvas_strokes', JSON.stringify(strokes)); 
    });
    $('#save-btn').click(function () {
        window.open(canvas[0].toDataURL());
    });
    $('#undo-btn').click(function (){
        strokes.pop();
        redraw();
    });
    $('#clear-btn').click(function (){
        strokes = [];
        redraw();
    });

    $('#color-picker').on('input', function () {
        brush.color = this.value;
    });
    $('#brush-size').on('input', function () {
        brush.size = this.value;
    });
    }
$(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<canvas id="draw"></canvas>

<button id="save-to-local-storage">
  Save 
</button>

<button id="clear-btn">
  clear
</button>
<button id="undo-btn">
  undo
</button>
```

I just want to add **google Maps** on canvas so that the user can draw on Google Maps rather than blank canvas. all other functionalities remain same. 
here is the code

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way for this to work is if you just make your canvas transparent and lay it over the top of a div element that contains a google static map. The map I'm using does not have markers on it, but you could make one that does. The map in this snippet won't show because you will need to add your API key.
Also, I disabled your localStorage because it gave me a CORS error in my console.

```js
var canvas, ctx,
  brush = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    color: '#000000',
    size: 10,
    down: false,
  },
  strokes = [],
  currentStroke = null;

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  for (var i = 0; i < strokes.length; i++) {
    var s = strokes[i];
    ctx.strokeStyle = s.color;
    ctx.lineWidth = s.size;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(s.points[0].x, s.points[0].y);
    for (var j = 0; j < s.points.length; j++) {
      var p = s.points[j];
      ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }

}

function init() {
  canvas = $('#draw');
  canvas.attr({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  });
  ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

  function mouseEvent(e) {
    brush.x = e.pageX;
    brush.y = e.pageY;

    currentStroke.points.push({
      x: brush.x,
      y: brush.y,

    });



    redraw();
  }
  canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
    brush.down = true;

    currentStroke = {
      color: brush.color,
      size: brush.size,
      points: [],
    };
    strokes.push(currentStroke);

    mouseEvent(e);
  }).mouseup(function(e) {
    brush.down = false;

    mouseEvent(e);

    currentStroke = null;
  }).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (brush.down)
      mouseEvent(e);
  });

  // check if localstorage has an array of strokes saved 
  //if (localStorage.getItem('canvas_strokes')) {
    //strokes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('canvas_strokes'));
    //redraw();
  //}

  $('#save-to-local-storage').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('canvas_strokes', JSON.stringify(strokes));
  });
  $('#save-btn').click(function() {
    window.open(canvas[0].toDataURL());
  });
  $('#undo-btn').click(function() {
    strokes.pop();
    redraw();
  });
  $('#clear-btn').click(function() {
    strokes = [];
    redraw();
  });

  $('#color-picker').on('input', function() {
    brush.color = this.value;
  });
  $('#brush-size').on('input', function() {
    brush.size = this.value;
  });
}
$(init);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#draw {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#map {
  background-image: url("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Fargo,ND&zoom=12&size=400x400&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <canvas id="draw"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="save-to-local-storage">
  Save 
</button>
<button id="clear-btn">
  clear
</button>
<button id="undo-btn">
  undo
</button>
```